# how to perform multiple updation with different id's in codeigniter mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, batch-updates

i have 2 tables:

table 1  ( leads_records ) -

```
lead_id , lead_number  
101     ,  852114774  
102     ,  3465799855  
103     ,  8797987979
```

table 2 (leads_assign) -

```
assign_id  , lead_id ,  lead_number  
1          ,  0      ,  852114774  
2          ,  0      ,  3465799855  
3          ,  0      ,  8797987979
```

I want to update lead_id in table 2 corresponding to lead_number
Example -

```
assign_id  , lead_id     ,      lead_number  
1          ,   101       ,       852114774  
2          ,   102       ,       3465799855  
3          ,   103       ,       8797987979
```

what query will use for batch_updating in CodeIgniter?
 I have used update_batch(''table','data','where') ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this ?

```
$this->db->query(
    "update leads_assign la
    JOIN leads_records lr ON la.lead_number = lr.lead_number
    set la.lead_id = lr.lead_id"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just calling the same `update_batch` method  with a different table and *where*?

```
$this->db->update_batch('leads_assign', $leads_records_data, 'lead_number');
```

Comment: I am confused to create an array for $leads_records_data with where condition.

Comment: Hmm, you say you have used "update_batch", can you add in your question the code you used for the update_batch from the first table?